# How to automate DatePicker in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

```
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=release_date</td>
    <td>2012-09-30</td>
</tr>
```

This works but I don't want to type the date but pick it using DatePicker and try automating it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will vary greatly depending on how your datepicker is coded. For example, I'm working on a Web app that utilizes Dojo and I'm using the following code to select a specific position within the datepicker pop-up instead of a particular date (because the actual date isn't important for my tests):

```
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>//*[@id=&quot;startDate&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>xpath=(//input[@value='▼ '])[3]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>//table[@id='startDate_popup']/tbody/tr/td[4]/span</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//table[@id='startDate_popup']/tbody/tr/td[4]/span</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I use `waitForElementPresent` frequently to make sure the JavaScript has time to complete running before the next step in the test is executed.

I've also found that `clickAt` is useful when clicking within Dojo widgets, and I typically prefer to use XPath for specific targets.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As newbie in Selenium IDE these days I done some tests who includes the date picker too.

I'll paste my HTML code, but if you have any problems or anything feel free to ask.

```
<!--Set some random generators for Hour From/To-->
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>[Math.floor((Math.random() * 31) + 1)]</td>
    <td>random</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//select[@id='valid']/option[3]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<!--Add values to From date and To date-->
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=p_date_from</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=${random}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//div[@id='valid_period']/p[2]/span/span/abbr</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>[Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)]</td>
    <td>random</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=${random}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```